# mysql column returns &amp; instead of &

Tags: php, mysql

I have description field in my MySQL table, one of its value store as `Jack & Jones` , but when I select and print it on my web page it is showing as `&amp;`
Can anyone help me? my requirement is to count string length and print sub-string but due to `&amp;` I am not getting actual result.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's impossible to give an intelligent answer without some details.

Comment: I have a table field say description and its value is Jack & Jones, when I select it like select description from my_table; and print it, it is showing as Jack &amp; Jones

Comment: You must be using libraries or something... template engine?

Comment: I am using e directory CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for character converter...

```
function unhtmlspecialchars( $string )
{
  $string = str_replace ( '&amp;', '&', $string );         
  return $string;
}
```

For direct conversion you can try :-

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you savinuclear, I have done same as you suggested but is there any way to directly fetch it decoded from table?

Comment: you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode($str);` to direct decode